What is the probabilty that station A will be closed exactly after 5 hours?
I have got a question for homework and I am not sure how to solve it.
The number of signal recived in station A in an hour are poisson  distributed with $\lambda=5$.
It's decided that station A will be closed after the first 2 consecutive hours that there won't be any signal recived in it.
what is the probability that station A will close after 5 hours?
I thought to go from looking on one hour units to 2 hour units (with the intersection between every 2 hours - for example: hours 1 - 2, hours 2 - 3 , ...) and using geometric distribution with $p=exp(-10)$ (for 2 hours without a signal) and sum the distribution from 4 to infinity (or to take the complementry case). The issue here is that I dont know how to approach geometric distribution with intersected cases.
Is this the right way to approach the problem? I will be happy to get the solution if possible.
thank you.

I am a little confused by the question. Are we looking for the probability that the station will be closed at $t = 5 \text{ hr}$? Or that the station will close sometime after $t = 5 \text{ hr}$?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4943260/poisson-question-number-of-signals-received-at-station-a
